# Managing ssl ciphersuites in Linux

Tags: configuration, ssl

Are the ciphersuites and encryption protocols allowed by an application managed *only* at the application, or can they be managed at the OS level?

Note: My experience with ssl is at the application level, not the os.

I have a vulnerability report stating that a particular app supports insecure cipher suites and deprecated protocols. I spoke with the application owner and he states that we should be able to disable all of this at the OS level.

So, I'd like to confirm: Can these be managed at the OS level, or are they managed at the application level? I have my thoughts, but I'd like to hear from those who know more about this than I do and get an idea of best practices.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what your application is written in and how it's hosted.  The question is a little vague as it stands.

Comment: Well, it's not *my* application, it's OMI. And I have no idea what it's written in. But I understand where you're coming from and sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restrict the allowed cipher suites by editing `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`. Documentation on the config file is spotty but a post on how to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68533896/how-to-force-openssl-config-to-use-tls-1-2-and-above).

Comment: Assuming the application is using OpenSSL...

Comment: @garethTheRed True. For GnuTLS, the appropriate configuration file is `/etc/gnutls/default-priorities`. I would expect that the large majority of Linux applications use either OpenSSL or GnuTLS with the former being somewhat more popular.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make my changes in the openssl.cnf file. I'll let you know how it goes.